# Participio passato dei verbi procomplementari in -sela, -sele, -selo

Tags: verbs, pronouns, past-participle, past-tense

I have several questions regarding the verbs such as *tirarsela, cavarsela, vignarsela*; *darsele, suonarsele*; and *scordarselo*, which are the so-called *verbi procomplementari*:

1. Do all of such verbs have a *participio passato*? For example, by searching in Google Books, I can find the *participio passato* such as [**cavatasela**](https://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&tbm=bks&ei=68j4XPGJIav1qwHrgoHAAQ&q=%22cavatasela%22&oq=%22cavatasela%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...54259.55649.0.55817.10.10.0.0.0.0.130.865.5j4.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.217...0i19k1.0.9WKBCCeV2Wc) but not such as [**cercatasela**](https://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&tbm=bks&ei=JMn4XLvuBc2urgT83I74Aw&q=%22cercatasela%22&oq=%22cercatasela%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...42898.44898.0.46467.11.11.0.0.0.0.120.1024.7j4.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.180...0i19k1.0.c76frUmED30).
2. What is the correct *participio passato* for such verbs: **cavatasela** or  **cavato/i/a/esela**, i.e. does the ending always remain the same depending on the *clitico* **la**, **le** or **lo**, or does it always change within the four forms in **-o/-a/-i/-e**? In Google Books, there are results for both [svignat**a**sela](https://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&tbm=bks&ei=Ysn4XIvxDqOurgSi24_oBw&q=%22svignatasela%22&oq=%22svignatasela%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...206358.208413.0.208845.12.12.0.0.0.0.126.1104.9j3.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.2.191...0i19k1.0.NSqfkXLLpko) and [svignat**o**sela](https://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&tbm=bks&ei=M8r4XPToHO2nrgS2uKbwDQ&q=%22svignatosela%22&oq=%22svignatosela%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14551.14703.0.15071.2.2.0.0.0.0.79.156.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.761kvPpPjHU) but only for [tirat**o**sela](https://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&tbm=bks&ei=Q8r4XNi2DOzkrgT5iqNQ&q=%22tiratasela%22&oq=%22tiratasela%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...51261.53733.0.53916.14.12.2.0.0.0.122.1078.10j2.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.297...0i19k1.0.ydpf_KtaDUA).
3. In accordance with question 2, what is the correct conjugation of such verbs in the *tempi composti*: *noi **ce la siamo tirata*** or *noi **ce la siamo tirati (tirate)***; *voi **ve lo siete scordato*** or *voi **ve le siete scordati (scordate)***, and so on?

Before asking, I have tried to find the answer in the article ['I verbi procomplementari tra grammatica e lessicografia'](https://www.academia.edu/359062/_I_verbi_procomplementari_tra_grammatica_e_lessicografia_) by A. Viviani. Here are several examples the researcher provides:

> - se la sono cavata (non sono stati puniti)
> - se la sono intesa per un anno e poi si sono lasciati
> - me la sono cavata
> - Carlo e Giacomo se le sono date per lei

This might suggest that the conjugation always depends on the *clitico*, but examples from Google Books show deviations from this assumption. I have sought the answer in the *Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione* by Renzi, Slavi, and Cardinaletti, but to no avail.

I would be grateful for any references to reliable academic sources.

Comment: They're not verbs on their own. I'm quite certain that one can find *scordatasela* in some book, but the clitic reflexive/medial particle *si* is not really used nowadays with the *participio passato* (and neither in other forms, except with the infinitive and in some fixed phrases such as *vendesi*).

Comment: I do not agree. They are classified as verbs on their own by De Mauro and a number of other linguists, as they are regarded as conveying a complex meaning in their entirety, with all the morphological components (even though other linguists might refrain from considering them as true verbs).

Comment: Everybody is entitled their own opinions. Anyway, the main point was not about the classification, but about current usage in Italian, which avoids the clitics as I said.

Comment: As @egreg says, while they might be considered verbs in their own right as regards their use and meaning, in their conjugation they follow their “parent” verb. So, apart from obsolete or literary usage, there is no such thing as _the_ participio passato of _cavarsela_, but rather the usual participio _cavata/e_ in a sentence where _se_ e _la/e_ also appear.

Comment: As regards De Mauro, just keep in mind that his dictionary follows a slightly different approach from other ones especially as regards its attention towards [polirematiche](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/9), so I'd say that the inclusion of verbi complementari as autonomous lemmas (which most other dictionaries don't do) fits in this approach.

Comment: Finally, as a personal opinion: *cavatasela* and the like are, if anything, statistical outliers, and on the same level as, say, *mangiatolo* and other constructions not involving verbi procomplementari.

Comment: @DaG Thank you for these answers. Would you have any ideas/sources for questions 2 and 3, namely for conjugation? I believe that the ending follows the clitic and not the person, but I have not been able to find any confirmation, and there is different usage in literature.

Comment: se la sono cavata -> cavatasela quella volta, hanno continuato a delinquere // 
se la sono intesa per un anno -> intesasela per un anno, poi si sono lasciati //
me la sono cavata -> cavatamela quella volta,  non ho più rischiato //
se le sono date per lei -> datesele per lei, poi ambedue l'hanno ignorata.  They sound fine to me.